# How can I re-format my DNA motifs' position weight matrices?

Tags: dna, transcription, software, gene-regulation, transcription-factor

I am working with a set of DNA motifs that are predicted as potential regulatory motifs (e.g. transcription factor binding sites).
The motifs belong to several species, and I wanted to cluster these motifs via their Position Weight Matrices (PWMs) (also known as PSSMs) to collapse similar motifs together into groups.

There is a tool called MATLIGN ([website here](http://ekhidna.biocenter.helsinki.fi/poxo/matlign/help#p0)) that does what I need, but their required format for the PWMs are different to what I have, they claim:

> "Matrices must be in the frequency matrix format (only integer numbers
>   are acceptable)"

The problem is that my PWM matrices do not have integer numbers but decimals instead. e.g.:

```
     A        C        G        T
1    0.000000 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
2    1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
3    0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
4    0.000000 0.421755 0.000000 0.578245
5    0.289407 0.000000 0.282556 0.428038
```

In other words, instead of the decimal values I have in my matrix I need to have integer counts. Could anybody suggest what I can do? Would I need to create artificial "pseudo-counts"?

Comment: Could it be so simple that they want counts of nucleotide occurances (the frequency) instead of proportions (e.g. your row 5 as (using n=60): 17 0 17 26)? Where do your numbers come from - I assume you have counts as raw data to calculate the proportions? Mind you, I have no experiance with these particular methods at all.

Comment: Thank you @fileunderwater for your comment. The problem is that the raw data is not available to me, what I have are the high level outputs the program had generated. I presume the whole integer counts are required by this software since proportions remain constant no matter how large the total.

Comment: ok, well then you have a problem, since there is no way of knowing the margin of error of the proportions. However, to get counts these proportions should just be multiplied by the number of binding sites included in the study. Don't you have that info (e.g. the number of sequnces that have been analysed)?

Comment: brilliant! I DO! you should make an answer of that! Thank you

Comment: Why not just multiply everything by 10? The PWM will still be correct since its values are relative to each other, you just make `1.00` into `10` and `0.28` into `28` etc.

Comment: Hi @terdon I was very tempted to do that before fileunderwater's answer came about. It turns out he was right, I eventually found in my dataset there was a "mysterious" variable called "nsites". After reading the small print of the docs, nsites is the number I should be multiplying by, since it is the number of DNA regions the motif was made under

Comment: Yes, his solution is cleaner but I doubt there will be any difference. Remember that PWMs are relative so multiplying by anything should be fine really.

Comment: @terdon As I wrote, I'm not familiar with this program/methods, but I assumed that the counts were used in the analysis to determine what confidence you can have in the proportions (i.e. more confidence in 33% from 40/120 than 3/9). But you might be correct that it doesn't make a difference in this case.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this program either but PWMs in general are always relative. What you get is a value indicating how often a particular residue is found a t a given position. Multiplying with an arbitrary value shouldn't affect the result in any way, as long as you multiple _all_ values. Basically 1 means you _always_ have that residue at that position. If you multiply by say 100, you can treat them as percentages. But yes, the implementations could vary depending on what you're feeding them to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what you need is basically your data expressed as counts instead of proportions. Even if you do not have the matrix of counts as raw data, these proportions only needs to be multiplied by the total number of binding sites used in the study (e.g. the number of sequences that have been analysed) to get the counts (since proportion = count/total number of binding sites). You should have that information somewhere.

@hello_there_andy: indeed there was this missing piece of information available to me, it came in the form of a variable called **nsites** which equates to the total number of DNA sites that the PWM was generated from.